# How to split single row values into multiple rows based on columns c#

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, multiple-columns, rows

I have a large csv file where there are multiple values that belong to different people store in the same row. Below you can find a sample of this data.

| country | country2 | country3 | name1 | name2 | name3 | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | UK | Australia | Michael | Mitchell | David | 222 | 333 | 444 |
| Colombia | Paraguay | Bolivia |  | John | Chris |  | 555 | 7777 |
| Brazil | Germany | Japan | Silvia | Ana |  | 888 | 999 |  |

I want to split this data so that I can keep the first 3 columns untouched and only format the rest, meaning that I will keep the format for country, country2 and country3 but name and phone will appear just once. The idea is that each person from the same row will have at the end the same 3 countries but its data will be viewed on a separate row in order to look like this:

| country | country2 | country3 | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | UK | Australia | Michael | 222 |
| USA | UK | Australia | Mitchell | 333 |
| USA | UK | Australia | David | 444 |
| Colombia | Paraguay | Bolivia |  |  |
| Colombia | Paraguay | Bolivia | John | 555 |
| Colombia | Paraguay | Bolivia | Chris | 7777 |
| Brazil | Germany | Japan | Silvia | 888 |
| Brazil | Germany | Japan | Ana | 999 |
| Brazil | Germany | Japan |  |  |

I have seen some examples based on SQL but I am trying to accomplish this on C# since I need to have the data set on this particular way so that I can do some other things with it before sending it to the database. I currently storing the data into a datatable but I am not sure how can I make this change without affecting the incosistency of the data. Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is the code that I have so far only to send this data to the datatable:

```
    public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you show a [mre] of what you have tried and explain how it's not working?

Comment: Hi, so far I am only storing the values into a datatable with the following function. I know I can create another data table that can start filling out the data row by row but I am still not sure how to indicate to this function to choose first only the column values with name 1 and phone 1 before jumping into name 2 and phone 2 and so on.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
 {
string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
 foreach (string header in headers)
    {
                    dt.Columns.Add(header);
                }
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
  string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
         {
                        dr[i] = rows[i];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            return dt;

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the information there. Reading long pieces of code in comments doesn't work very well and it's also essential information to the question, so it fits better in the question.

Comment: Ok I will add that no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that your test csv file looks like that:

```
USA;UK;Australia;Michael;Mitchell;David;222;333;444
Colombia;Paraguay;Bolivia;;John;Chris;;555;7777
Brazil;Germany;Japan;Silvia;Ana;;888;999;;
```

You will get what you want in `modifiedData` variable:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace CsvMod
{
    public class OriginalData
    {
        public string Country1 { get; set; }
        public string Country2 { get; set; }
        public string Country3 { get; set; }
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public string Name3 { get; set; }
        public string Phone1 { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        public string Phone3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModifiedData
    {
        public string Country1 { get; set; }
        public string Country2 { get; set; }
        public string Country3 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");

            var originalData = new List<OriginalData>();

            foreach (var line in csvLines)
            {
                var items = line.Split(';');

                originalData.Add(new OriginalData
                {
                    Country1 = items[0],
                    Country2 = items[1],
                    Country3 = items[2],
                    Name1 = items[3],
                    Name2 = items[4],
                    Name3 = items[5],
                    Phone1 = items[6],
                    Phone2 = items[7],
                    Phone3 = items[8],
                });
            }

            var modifiedData = new List<ModifiedData>();

            foreach (var item in originalData)
            {
                modifiedData.AddRange(new List<ModifiedData>
                {
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = item.Country1,
                        Country2 = item.Country2,
                        Country3 = item.Country3,
                        Name = item.Name1,
                        Phone = item.Phone1,
                    },
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = item.Country1,
                        Country2 = item.Country2,
                        Country3 = item.Country3,
                        Name = item.Name2,
                        Phone = item.Phone2,
                    },
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = item.Country1,
                        Country2 = item.Country2,
                        Country3 = item.Country3,
                        Name = item.Name3,
                        Phone = item.Phone3,
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you really trust your data, then one LINQ statement and `result` contains the same:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CsvMod
{
    public class ModifiedData
    {
        public string Country1 { get; set; }
        public string Country2 { get; set; }
        public string Country3 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");

            var result = csvLines.Aggregate(new List<ModifiedData>(), (acc, x) =>
            {
                var items = x.Split(';');

                acc.AddRange(new List<ModifiedData>
                {                    
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = items[0],
                        Country2 = items[1],
                        Country3 = items[2],
                        Name = items[3],
                        Phone = items[6],
                    },
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = items[0],
                        Country2 = items[1],
                        Country3 = items[2],
                        Name = items[4],
                        Phone = items[7],
                    },
                    new ModifiedData
                    {
                        Country1 = items[0],
                        Country2 = items[1],
                        Country3 = items[2],
                        Name = items[5],
                        Phone = items[8],
                    },
                });

                return acc;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at all, I've updated the the answer, so it you have time, you can learn LINQ, sometimes it help to make work with enumerable data easier! :)